# Wiring multispeed PSC motor from ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan, electric-motor

I disassembled a ceiling fan to replace seized bearings. Unfortunately the pics I took to aid re-assembly are no longer accessible and the fan is an '80s era no-brand which I can't find any info for online.
 I have determined this is a PSC motor with a 3-wire speed control (L-->off / L-->A / L-->B / L-->A+B), a DPDT reverse switch and a single non-polarized capacitor. The motor has 5 colored leads (red, black, grey, green, brown) and I measured resistance as follows:
 Black-Red=30
Red-Grey=60
Black-Grey=90
 I'm doing my best to understand it but I'm still a little confused about how to re-connect it all. I made a diagram and took the liberty of numbering all the leads in order to aid discussion. Any help would be much appreciated - thanks! [image: ceiling fan motor diagram]

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution so I'm going to to go ahead and post it in case anyone else should happen upon this and find it useful.
I added the 1-in, 2-out, 4-position speed switch into the diagram. The switch works by taking one input and routing it thusly:
[1:  (off) | 2:A | 3:B | 4:A+B]
 and in this way controls speed by energizing either one part, 2 parts, or all 3 parts of the run (inner) winding (see diagram to help make sense of this).
I found conflicting information about achieving reverse (some sources said switch the polarity of the run winding, some said the start winding); I went with the start winding (the outer one) and it worked. Lastly, I found the capacitor was to be inserted in the start winding and that was straightforward enough.
With the AC input I made red Hot and blue Neutral; however it doesn't appear to me it would make any difference, other than that one way the reverse switch is up for clockwise rotation and the other it is up for counterclockwise rotation.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought this was an interesting question. I guessed the  R, B, and Gry wires terminals correctly when you first posted the question and couldn't figure out the wiring for the reverse switch. Glad you got it working.